When using the baby step giant step algorithm, how to decrease the number of operation at the cost of memory when computing several discrete logs?
The usual baby step giant step algorithm has a complexity in $O(\sqrt n)$ in both memory and number of operations.
I read several time that it’s possible to increase the memory complexity in order to decrease the number of computations : this something interesting in my case since I have enough memory to store 238 operations.
But how this can be done exactly ? Is it also true Pollard’s rho/Kangaroo can’t be modified in the same way ? I’m also interested in the case of searching the discrete logarithm between a same public key and several starting elements : eg : having public key $P$ an solving the discrete logarithm both between $P$ and $A$ and between $P$ and $B$. And where finding a single relation out of the several posssibilities defeat the system (not having to compute all the possible discrete logarithms).

Daniel S answered your question already for the case of counting the total amount of computation needed. In case you discount the work needed for precomputation, more memory helps, as you can see for example in The Discrete-Logarithm Problem
with Preprocessing by Henry Corrigan-Gibbs and Dmitry Kogan.

You seem to be interested mostly in elliptic curves, but for discrete logs with precomputation in multiplicative groups of finite fields you could take a look at Imperfect Forward Secrecy: How Diffie-Hellman Fails in Practice.

It isn't possible. To access memory will take at least one operation and so the number of operations must be at least as large as the memory utilised.
It is however possible to decrease the memory usage by increasing the number of operations. Essentially split $n$ into 2 approximate pieces $g$ and $b$ (e.g. high bits and low bits) so that $n\approx gb$. Now, precompute $g$ giant steps, store and sort. Then for $b$ baby steps, compute the target divided by the baby step and search for matches in the giant step list.
This takes $g\log g+b\log g$ operations and $g$ memory. We can balance the operations by taking $b = g \approx \sqrt n$, or we can use less memory e.g. by taking $g\approx n^{1/4}$ and $b\approx n^{3/4}$.
By contrast, Pollard's kangaroo takes $O(1)$ memory. Increasing the memory by using more traps does not decrease the operation count, but does have parallelism benefits.

Isn’t there a generic algorithm that can work in a subgroup/suborder that can take advantage of having large amount of memory ?

No. Victor Shoup has shown that in "generic groups" of order $p$, at least $\Omega(p^{1/2})$ operations are required to solve discrete logarithms. See Lower bounds for discrete logarithms and related problems

What about the special case in my question edit ? I see that some computations can be reused in the case of shanks algorithm but is it possible to do it better ?

@user2284570 It's probably worth asking that one as a separate question.

Recall the Baby Step/Giant Step algorithm to solve a Discrete Logarithm Problem, that is find $x$ in $[0,n)$ such that $[x]G=Y$ given $G$ and $Y$ in a group (noted additively) of order $n$.

We choose integer $g$, typically with $g$ of bit size close to that of $\sqrt n$, and compute $b=\left\lceil n/g\right\rceil$. We can write $x=u\,b+v$ for some unknown integers $u,v$ with $0\le u<g$, $0\le v<b$. For these, it must hold $[u]([b]G)=Y-[v]G$.
We precompute and store the $g$ elements $[u]([b]G)$, which requires one group multiplication for $[b]G$, then $g$ group additions: one of each of the $g$ "giant steps" adding $[g]G$; and storing the $g$ results in a data structure appropriate for fast search by value.
For each element $Y-[v]G$ for $v$ increasing from $0$ to at most $b-1$, we compute that element, and search it among the $g$ stored $[u]([b]G)$. Each computation uses a single group addition for a "baby step" adding $-G$, and standard techniques make each search fast, nearly independent of $n$ and $g$ ignoring caching effects. When we get a match, we have $u$ and $v$, thus $x$, and stop with the result $x=u\,b+v$.

Time is dominated by $g$ group additions and entering the result in the data structure at step 2, and on average $b/2$ group additions and searching the result at step 3. Memory requirement increases about linearly with $g$.
When we are trying to solve $k$ DLPs differing only by the value of $Y$, only step 3 needs to be redone for each $Y$.
For simplification assume the cost for a step of 2 is the same as for a step of 3, and is independent of $g$. The expected cost to solve $k$ DLPs is about $g+k\,n/(2g)$ operations, each operations being a group addition, and some memory operations of cost roughly fixed when $n$ and $g$ vary.
That cost is a function of $g$, with a minimum $\approx\sqrt{2k\,n}$ for $g\approx\sqrt{k\,n/2}$. Thus when we are not memory bound, we can solve $k$ DLPs at only $\sqrt k$ of the cost of solving one, and the optimal amount of precomputations (thus roughly, optimal memory usage) grows as $\sqrt k$.

In summary, when we need $k$ solutions to $k$ DLPs (but not when we are trying to solve one of $k$ DLPs), we can make use of more memory to slightly lower the average attack time per solution found.
But this is mostly theoretical: in problems of practical interest in cryptography $n$ is so large that memory considerations require $g\ll\sqrt{n/2}$, thus there is essentially no gain to attacking several DLPs simultaneously. At $n=70$ we'd need terabytes of memory (in practice, RAM) for this strategy to pay off. And is we pay RAM by the time it's used, it's not economical.
That's why straight BS/GS is not used in practice: it requires impractically much RAM.

Isn't this similar to the gain of the wiener parallelization? though there, as far as I recall, too late at night here, there is a single target

@fgrieu nice but I m interested in how to do it exactly. What s the algorithm? I need to compare a public key against $2^{21}$ values. Solving only 1 of the discrete logarithm relations between 1 out of the $2^{21}$ values deafeats the system. All of this happening in 70 bits long subgroups. But performing a single operation is computationally costly (elliptic curve point exponentiation).

@user2284570: so your want to implement BS/GS for an Elliptic Curve group with in the order of $n\approx2^{70}$ elements. You want to use two techniques 1) for both the baby steps and the giant steps, each step requires a single point addition (I now explain how). 2) Search for an exact match in a large set can be cheap, with cost nearly independent of the set size (except for cache effects). That's built into some languages like Python, or libraries like std::set of C++, or implementable explicitly in any Turing-complete language like C.

@fgrieu I was reading a paper about multiplicative discrete logarithm instead of the usual additive. I was reading their bsgs implementation and it s unclear how to do it with pollard rho. What I think can help is having many multiple possible sources for the same target.

@user2284570: Multiplicative/additive is a matter of notation only. Algorithms are the same, with e.g. inversion replaced by negation. Pollard's rho works for DLP, see e.g. this. Pollard's rho does more computations than BS/GS, but uses little memory thus is better for large problems. It's possible to transform one DLP into $k$ equivalent DLPs. However the saving I describe for that when there is ample memory is for solving $k$ DLPs, not one of $k$ DLPs, thus this transformation does not help.

@fgrieu hemm no. As an example, try to find a pollard rho equivalent of this varient that shift ecdlp solving to other subgroups through exponentiation. You ll likely only find Pollard Kangaroo and no Pohlig Hellman without auxiliary inputs.

@user2284570: the reference I link to above describes a generic Pollard's rho for the DLP in any finite cyclic (thus commutative) group where we can partition efficiently from the representation of an element. And I don't understand what's attempted in the code you link to: lines 1-10 define secp256k1, and the DLP in that group is believed intractable. Also, I don't see a 70-bit (sub) group as in some above comments.

@fgrieu simple: the code attempt to solve discrete logarithms by lifting the ecdlp to $prime−1$ since most prime curves have smooth order in that case (or $order−1$ in my case since I m using a curve extension field). But that currently only works if the key is already in a subgroup as moving the key itself to suborders seems to require auxiliary inputs discribed by Cheon.

@user2284570: ah that's about Cheon's algorithm, which seems to aim at solving for $x$ given both $[x]G$ and $[x^d]G$ for some (given) $d$ that divides $p-1$ where $p$ is the group order. I'm not familiar with that, but I'm inclined to believe that source stating Pollard's rho is applicable for that.

@fgrieu but the varient in the code https://github.com/cysecud/ecc_weak_keys/blob/master/gp_code/alg.gp#L21 works without auxiliary inputs.

@user2284570: Is there at least a writeup on how this is supposed to work? Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence!

@fgrieu not an extraordinary claim. Again try to move a key to a subgroup and it will likely require billions of auxiliary inputs. It only works without auxilliary inputs if a given key is already in a subgroup hence the name weak keys of the repository.

@user2284570: Again, "if a given key is already in a subgroup" does not make sense to me in the context of secp256k1, or most of the secp????? curves since their order is prime, hence any subgroup is the full group or the singleton. I do not challenge that we can find a class of keys that an algorithm can break; but if the class contains a sizable subset of $p'$ keys out of $p$, I'm ready to bet we don't get a speedup sizably better than a factor $p/p'$, and I can only make examples where that speedup is by $\sqrt{p/p'}$ (e.g. the subset of $p'≈p/d$ keys with private key multiple of $d$).

@fgrieu Ok. J ai retrouvé le papier https://eprint.iacr.org/2024/1321 They indeed move the problem to an other order. They even state To counteract the positive impact of using the iBSGS algorithm, a possible solution would be to standardize elliptic curves whose group order is a safe prime, i.e., a prime  such that  = 2 + 1 Also, their rust or Pari code works.

@user2284570: the paper defines a weak (public, private) key pair as one $(Y=[k]G,k)$ where $k$ has a low order in $\mathbb Z_p^$. Problem is, that definition does not correspond to any actual weakness. Argument: whatever public integer $j$ we take, that $k-j$ has a low order in $\mathbb Z_p^$ is just as threatening, for we could apply whatever algorithm threatens finding $k$ from $Y$ to find $k-j$ from $Y-[j]G$, then find $k$. It follows that choosing a random $k$ that match their "weakness" criteria is no more dangerous than choosing any random $k$. The paper is pointless for classic ECC.

@fgrieu of course. Je n ai jamais dit que c était utile beside their promise to look for Pohlig Hellman in future research.
